# length of undefined error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

From the following code, if i try console `a.length` it returns me the value `6`, but if i try to assign the same to some other variable or try to return the value of `a.length` it throws me `'length' of undefined` error.

```js
function ResizeUI() {
  var a = $("#ao-sales-histroy-grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames');
  console.log(a.length); //returns me 6
  if ((a.length) < 10) { //returns error - 'length' of undefined
    if ($("#ao-sales-histroy-container").width() !== 0) {
      $('#ao-sales-histroy-grid').setGridWidth($("#ao-sales-histroy-container").width() - 10);
    }

  }
}
```

when i try to log `a` it returns me :

```js
[
  "Sku Department", 
  "Giveaways and Samples<br><input type='checkbox' na…  onclick = 'SHRowcheckBox(this,event)' ></input>", 
  "Supplies<br><input type='checkbox' name='SHMatrixC…  onclick = 'SHRowcheckBox(this,event)' ></input>", 
  "Displays<br><input type='checkbox' name='SHMatrixC…  onclick = 'SHRowcheckBox(this,event)' ></input>", 
  "Magazines<br><input type='checkbox' name='SHMatrix…  onclick = 'SHRowcheckBox(this,event)' ></input>", 
  "Total"
]
```

Error scenarios:

condition 1: [image]

condition 2: [image]

may be a small and stupid mistake, but please do help.
thanks in advance!!.

Comment: @KevinL in that case, it should give `length` as `undefined` and should not throw error

Comment: Your if condition should be  if (a && (a.length) < 10)

Comment: @Jai It will return `undefined`. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/rys122ca/)

Comment: 6.length throws  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: @ IamSarav - We're clearly going to need more information here, see Kevin L's and Rajesh's comments. Ideally, create a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: @rishabhdev: Only because `6` is a numeric literal. To correctly read a `length` property from the numeric *literal*, you need `(6).length` (or `6..length`). Or use a variable: `var x = 6; x.length;`

Comment: Apologies :(  i have corrected the question with my actual problem. pls check it. and its not throwing error, but its not returning the value what i want.

Comment: @IamSarav: Re your edit: I can tell you quite definitely that if `console.log(a.length);` gives you `6` in the console, then `if ((a.length) < 10)` absolutely **does not** throw an error.

Comment: @IamSarav may be you are calling resizeUi several times and for some case variable a is undefined. better to check if a is available by doing this: (a && (a.length) < 10)

Comment: I tried '(a && (a.length) < 10)' but its giving ''length' of undefined' error only

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not getting the right result from the first jquery line.

You could check a for being falsy or null before using the a.length property as below: -

```
if(a && a.length) {
   // do stuff here
}
```

But you also need to investigate, what value is being returned by jq.